# What is a lambda expression?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lambda, expression-trees

What is Significance of using lambda expressions.

like in C# there foreach loop which might take 3-4 line for assigning values

using lamba

```
List.foreach(x=>x.something = new value)
```

I would like to know more on lambda and more advance uses of it in C#

Comment: I can't believe this isn't a duplicate... if it is however I don't think it's a bad question (with a bit of tidying).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda expression is more a less a short hand syntax for a method.

Take the following lambda expression:

```
p => p.FullName
```

This is equivalent to:

```
string getFullName(Person p)
{
    return p.FullName;
}
```

Its usage allows you to create anonymous functions. So a method that would take a delegate would be defined as:

```
public delegate string FullNameDelegate(Person p);
public void DoSomething(FullNameDelegate getter)
{
   Person p = new Person();
   string fullname = getter(p);
}
public string GetFullName(Person p)
{
    return p.FullName;
}

DoSomething(new FullNameDelegate(GetFullName));
```

The lambda equivalent would be:

```
public void DoSomething(Func<Person, string> getter)
{
   Person p = new Person();
   string fullname = getter(p);
}

DoSomething(p => p.FullName);
```